# Poker hand string display

Tags: python, string, list, search

I'm brand new to programming and Python and I'm trying my hardest to understand and learn it. I'm not asking for answers but explanations in plain non-computer terms so that i can try to work out the solution myself.

Here is one more problem I'm having. I have 4 lists below:

```
short_card = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'T', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
long_card = ['ace', 'king', 'queen', 'jack', 'ten', 'nine', 'eight', 'seven', 'six', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'deuce']
short_suit = ['c', 'd', 'h', 's']
long_suit = ['clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'spades']
```

Now what im supposed to do is write two functions: card_str(c) and hand_str(h).

card_str(c) takes a two character string and searches to find out the corresponding characters to display the card in text. For instance if I put 'kh' the program will output "King of Hearts".

hand_str(h) takes a list of two character strings and displays the appropriate hand in full text. Again for instance if I put (["Kh", "As", "5d", "2c"]), it will output "King of Hearts, Ace of Spades, Five of Diamonds, Deuce of Clubs".

Below is what I have so far:

```
short_card = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'T', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
long_card = ['ace', 'king', 'queen', 'jack', 'ten', 'nine', 'eight', 'seven', 'six',      'five', 'four', 'three', 'deuce']
short_suit = ['c', 'd', 'h', 's']
long_suit = ['clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'spades']

def card_str(c):

def hand_str(h):


#- test harness: do not modify -# 

for i in range(13):  
print card_str(short_card[i] + short_suit[i%4])

l = []
for i in range(52):
    l.append(short_card[i%13] + short_suit[i/13])
print hand_str(l)
```

Comment: remember im a beginner with no knowledge in python or its functions. Can anyone explain an easy way to output the result i need?

Comment: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812): state any special restrictions, **show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.**  You need to work a bit harder on what you have so far, such as attempting to implement those functions (include code above) and asking about specific problems in those implementations.  As it stands, this is "please explain this assignment for me" with no work from you, which makes for a really poor question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have much, but I'll say that your lists are in pairs.

```
short_card = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'T', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
long_card = ['ace', 'king', 'queen', 'jack', 'ten', 'nine', 'eight', 'seven', 'six', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'deuce']
```

and

```
short_suit = ['c', 'd', 'h', 's']
long_suit = ['clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'spades']
```

They're each the same length and in the same order. So the index of 'A' in short_card is the same as the index of 'ace' in long_card. So if you find the index of one, you have the index of the other.

This should point you in the right direction. Come back and edit your post when you have more.

Comment: What are you having problems with? Update your question with what you've tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

So what you have is two sets of lists, which correlate the input values with the output strings.  Note the order of the lists; they're the same.  Which should make the index values of the inputs equal to the...

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it slightly differently to the last two posters, and start with the `zip` function for joining up matching lists.

Comment: @downvoter: You should leave a comment and explain why downvoting was necessary!

Comment: How would you possibly use zip for this that would help in any way?

Comment: Remember "last two posters" loses meaning quickly on SO.  This isn't a great answer (the question has problems in the first place), but I'm not sure it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Falmarri: for a, b in zip(short_card, long_card): if a == needle: return b

Comment: this seems too complicated for a newbie like me :P

Comment: @justin, @Roger Pate: I would use zip and dict to map the single letter codes to the full names. Then all you have to do is look up the code letters: `cardname = cards[cardcode]`. That's much more readable than solutions based on index, and is a better habit to get into (it would be faster for large datasets). I was trying not to give too much away, as it sounds like a homework thing, but I guess I misjudged it. And yes, the 'last two posters' thing was stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def poker_card(c):
...     card, suit = c
...     short_cards = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'T', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
...     short_suits = ['c', 'd', 'h', 's']
...     long_cards = ['ace', 'king', 'queen', 'jack', 'ten', 'nine', 'eight', 'seven', 'six',      'five', 'four', 'three', 'deuce']
...     long_suits = ['clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts', 'spades']
...     return "%s of %s" % (long_cards[short_cards.index(card)], long_suits[short_suits.index(suit)])
... 
>>> def poker_hand(hand):
...     return [poker_card(c) for c in hand]
... 
>>> def main():
...     print poker_hand(["Kh", "As", "5d", "2c"])
... 
>>> main()
['king of hearts', 'ace of spades', 'five of diamonds', 'deuce of clubs']
```