# Python Card Display

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Poker hand string display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170238/poker-hand-string-display)

hi all im having a bit of a hard time figuring this question out . so if i can get any help i would greatly appreciate it. the question is ;

Create functions card_str(c) and hand_str(h) which return a string version of a card and a hand of
cards, respectively. A card is a string of two characters: a rank followed by a suit. A hand is a list of
cards.

```
>>> print card_str("Kh")
king of hearts
>>> print hand_str([’Kh’, ’As’, ’5d’, ’2c’])
king of hearts, ace of spades, five of diamonds, deuce of clubs
```

Thanks for your time and explaining.

Comment: @derekerdmann: ["The homework tag...is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @sam, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: I don't think that "not a real question" is a good reason to close this. The question is clearly "Will you do my homework for me?" "exact duplicate" is the way to go here. and -1 for duplicating what I can only presume is either your own question or that of a classmate as it is literally _the exact same assignment_.

Comment: @aaronasterling: The linked duplicate is a candidate for "unreal question" too: all that's happened is typing in the assignment and asking "could you please explain it?"  (That is, my comment on it with bold.)  This has the same problems.

Comment: @Roger Pate, I don't really care how it gets closed as long as it does but I can look at both question and know exactly what's required for a solution. That, to me, makes it a real question. I'm really just splitting hairs here.

Comment: @aaronasterling: I realize duplicate fits perfectly here, but "unreal" includes "cannot be reasonably answered", which, IMHO, fits such "typed assignment + asked for vague help + did no work except two short lines of code" posts (no matter how polite the poster is about it).

Answer (score 1):

For `card_str(c)`, you need to convert a combination of value and suit ('Kh', for example), and convert it into a longer string. You'll need to create lists that contain:

1. A dictionary mapping short values (e.g. 'K' or 'A' to long names, 'King' and 'Ace')
2. A dict mapping short suit names to full name ('c' goes to clubs, etc.)

You can then then return `valdict[c[0]] + 'of' + suitdict[c[1]]` (the first element in the argument's long value name + the second element in the argument's long suit name).

For `hand_str(c)`, take the list of card names you have, and construct a new list by iterating through `c` and calling `hand_str` on each element of `c`. Then return your new list.

Since this is homework, I'll leave the implementation to you. If you get stuck, check out the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you used python dictionaries before?  I might try something like follows.

```
rank_dict = {"A" : "Ace", "K" : "King", "Q" : "Queen", "J" : "Jack",....}
suit_dict = {"h" : "Hearts", "s" : "Spades", "c" : "Clubs", "d" : "Diamonds"}
```

Then you can do something like follows.

```
card_string = "Kh"
print(rank_dict[card_string[0:1]] + " of " + suit_dict[card_string[1:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to get started would be to write out some or all of the input-output pairs.

So you might begin with:

```
Kh king of hearts
As ace of spades
...
```

Once you have that table, you'll be able to find the commonalities; the pattern.  Once you find that, code it up!

Comment: We know the pattern already, it's fairly straight forward

Comment: We do, he doesn't... it's homework.